# Javascript iteration of objects

Tags: javascript

The state variable is the data I'm working on. The numbers are optionIds.

```
var state = {0: {classification: 'uretim', description: 'Planlı Uretim'},
                1: {classification: 'uretim', description: 'Plansız Uretim'},
                2: {classification: 'hata', description: 'Planlı Hata', color: 'red'},
                3: {classification: 'hata', description: 'Plansız Hata', color: '#ff6666'},
                4: {classification: 'yokluk', description: 'Planlı Yokluk', color: 'grey'},
                5: {classification: 'yokluk', description: 'Plansız Yokluk', color: '#D3D3D3'},
                6: {classification: 'kurulum', description: 'Planlı Kurulum', color: 'blue'},
                7: {classification: 'kurulum', description: 'Plansız Kurulum', color: '#ADD8E6'}
                };
```

In this function, the values in state object are being classified. But currently It's not working properly. "i" variable should stay same for the same classification. For instance, for "uretim" it should not change, it must be "0" for 0 and 1 optionIds

```
function createData(state, data) {

        var dataSet = [];
        var i = 0;

        for (var optionId in state) {
            if (state.hasOwnProperty(optionId)) {

                dataSet.push({
                    label: state[optionId].description,
                    //In this line "i" should be same value for the same classifications. For instance it should be 0 for "uretim"(0 and 1 optionIds)
                    data: [[i, count]]
                });
                i++;
            }
        }
        return dataSet;
}
```

The structure of state variable should not be changed. Please note that.

Comment: Please proofread your title.

Comment: What do you mean, "it should not change"? Then don't do `i++`?

Answer (score 1):

```
var state = {0: {classification: 'uretim', description: 'Planlı Uretim'},
                1: {classification: 'uretim', description: 'Plansız Uretim'},
                2: {classification: 'hata', description: 'Planlı Hata', color: 'red'},
                3: {classification: 'hata', description: 'Plansız Hata', color: '#ff6666'},
                4: {classification: 'yokluk', description: 'Planlı Yokluk', color: 'grey'},
                5: {classification: 'yokluk', description: 'Plansız Yokluk', color: '#D3D3D3'},
                6: {classification: 'kurulum', description: 'Planlı Kurulum', color: 'blue'},
                7: {classification: 'kurulum', description: 'Plansız Kurulum', color: '#ADD8E6'}
                };
function classification(state){
var dataSet = [];
        var i = 0;
    let classKeys={}
        for (var optionId in state) {

            if (state.hasOwnProperty(optionId)) {
              if(!classKeys[state[optionId].classification]){
                  classKeys[state[optionId].classification]=i
                  i++
              }
                dataSet.push({
                    label: state[optionId].description,
                    data:{classKey:classKeys[state[optionId].classification,count}

                });

            }
        }
        console.log(dataSet);

}
```

You need to save the 0,1,2.... for each classification into classKey 
Hope it insights something
Cheers..